# Display DOM node in multiple places w/o cloning/copying

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Disclaimer:

I've blathered on kind-of excessively here in an attempt to provide enough context to pre-empt all questions you folks might have of me. Don't be scared by the length of this question: much of what I've written is *very* skim-able (especially the potential solutions I've come up with).

## Goal:

The effect I'm hoping to achieve is displaying the same element (and all descendants) in multiple places on the same page. My current solution (see below for more detail) involves having to clone/copy and then append in all the other places I want it to appear in the DOM. What I'm asking for here is a better (more efficient) solution. I have a few ideas for potentially more efficient solutions (see below). Please judge/criticize/dismiss/augment those, or add your own more-brilliant-er solution!

### "Why?" you ask?

Well, the element (and it's descendants) that I'm wanting to display more than once potentially has lots of attributes and contents - so cloning it, and appending it someplace else (sometimes more than one other place) can get to be quite a resource-hogging DOM manipulation operation.

### Some context:

I can't describe the situation exactly (damn NDA's!) but *essentially* what I've got is a WYSIWYG html document editor. When a person is editing the DOM, I'm actually saving the "original" node and the "changed" node by wrapping them both in a div, hiding the "original" and letting the user modify the new ("changed") node to their heart's content. This way, the user can easily review the changes they've made before saving them.

Before, I'd just been letting the user navigate through the "diff divs" and temporarily unhiding the "original" node, to show the changes "inline". What I'm trying to do now is let the user see the whole "original" document, and their edited ("changed") document in a side-by-side view. And, potentially, I'd like to save the changes through multiple edit sessions, and show 'N' number of versions side-by-side simultaneously.

### Current Solution:

My current solution to achieve this effect is the following:

Wrap the whole dang dom (well, except the "toolbars" and stuff that they aren't actually editing) in a div (that I'll call "pane1"), and create a new div (that I'll call "pane2"). Then deep-clone pane1's contents into pane2, and in pane1 only show the "original" nodes, and in pane2 only show the "changed" nodes (in the diff regions - everything outside of that would be displayed/hidden by a toggle switch in a toolbar). Then, repeat this for panes 3-through-N.

### Problem with Current Solution:

If the document the user is editing gets super long, or contains pictures/videos (with different src attributes) or contains lots of fancy styling things (columns, tables and the like) then the DOM can potentially get very large/complex, and trying to clone and manipulate it can make the browser slow to a crawl or die (depending on the DOM's size/complexity and how many clones need to be made as well as the efficiency of the browser/the machine it's running on). If size is the issue I can certainly do things like actually remove the hidden nodes from the DOM, but that's yet more DOM manipulation operations hogging resources.

### Potential Solutions:

#### 1. Find a way to make the DOM more simple/lightweight

so that the cloning/manipulating that I'm currently doing is more efficient. (of course, I'm trying to do this as much as I can *anyway*, but perhaps it's all I can really do).

#### 2. Create static representations of the versions with Canvas elements or something.

I've heard there's a trick where you can wrap HTML in an SVG element, then use that as an image source and draw it onto a canvas. I'd think that those static canvasses (canvi?) would have a much smaller memory footprint than cloned DOM nodes. And manipulating the DOM (hiding/showing the appropriate nodes), then drawing an image (rinse & repeat) should be quicker & more efficient than cloning a node and manipulating the clones. (maybe I'm wrong about that? Please tell me!)

I've tried this in a limited capacity, but wrapping my HTML in SVG messes with the way it's rendered in a couple of weird cases - perhaps I just need to message the elements a bit to get them to display properly.

#### 3. Find some magic element

that just refers to another node and looks/acts like it without being a real clone (and therefore being somehow magically much more lightweight). Even if this meant that I couldn't manipulate this magic element separately from the node it's "referencing" (or its fake children) - in that case I could still use this for the unchanged parts, and hopefully shave off some memory usage/DOM Manipulation operations.

#### 4. Perform some of the steps on the server side.

I do have the ability to execute server side code, so maybe it's a lot more efficient (some of my users *might* be on mobile or old devices) to get all ajax-y and send the relevant part of the DOM (could be the "root" of the document the user is editing, or just particularly heavy "diff divs") to the server to be cloned/manipulated, then request the server-manipulated "clones" and stick 'em in their appropriate panes/places.

#### 5. Fake it to make it "feel" more efficient

Rather than doing these operations all in one go and making the browser wait till the operations are done to re-draw the UI, I could do the operations in "chunks" and let the browser re-render and catch a breather before doing the next chunk. This probably actually would result in more time spent, but to the casual user it might "feel" quicker (haha, silly fools...). In the end, I suppose, it *is* user experience that is what's  most important.

### Footnote:

Again, I'm NDA'd which prevents me from posting the actual code here, as much as I'd like to. I *think* I've thoroughly explained the situation (perhaps *too thoroughly* - if such a thing exists) so it shouldn't be necessary for you to see code to give me a general answer. If need be, I suppose I could write up some example code that differs enough from my company's IP and post it here. Let me know if you'd like me to do that, and I'll be happy to oblige (well, not really, but I'll do it anyway).

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL - Sorry, but "Sorry, but... what?" what?

Comment: @Dave Thomas - yeah, especially for the folks using mobile devices, I'm thinking this solution shows promise. I suppose a good solution #6 would be "some clever combination of these tricks..."

Comment: is this a thesis paper or what? can you at least boil down to the point of the iceberg?

Comment: @Joseph - har har har, it is a bit thesis-sized, but I don't know how to boil it down any more than I did in that "Goal" section...

Comment: I actually read the whole damn thing! =P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [CSS background elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-element). They allow you to display DOM nodes elsewhere/repeatedly. They are of course they are read-only, but should update live.

You may still have to come up with a lot of magic around them, but it is a similar solution to:

> 1. Create static representations of the versions with Canvas elements or something.

CSS background elements are also very experimental, so you may not get very far with them if you have to support a range of browsers.

Comment: It's probably a bit early to use these features.

Comment: @Chaos fortunately for me, using bleeding-edge stuff is kind of a plus, though certainly not if nobody can actually use it. It seems that article claims that currently only firefox uses it, is that out of date, or still true? I'll test it out at work mañana. And, honestly, I'm _most_ concerned about the "mobile" devices in terms of performance. Most of the desktop environments I'm after should be able to manage - unless the DOMs get humongous.

Comment: So, for the record, I'm accepting this answer 'cause it's what I was really looking for (I knew I'd heard of this before, but couldn't find it again, so thanks!) but I'm giving Chaos the bounty 'cause it appears to have put more thought into its answer.

Comment: I actually missed the part about mobile devices! Pretty challenging to be able to give the user all those features in a mobile. Too hard basket! Considering your compatibility limitations, I'd throw out CSS background elements as it only works for FF (probably not the mobile version of FF) and FF mobile is currently only available for Android. Silverlight will work in Windows phone 7, but who owns one of those? Btw, thanks JKing, it is a thought-provoking question.

Comment: Alas, my bounty has been plundered! :P

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, after reading the question I almost left thinking it belongs in the "too-hard-basket", but after some thought perhaps I have some ideas.

This is a really difficult problem and the more I think about it the more I realise that there is no real way to escape needing to clone. You're right in that you can create an SVG or Canvas but it won't look the same, though with a fair amount of effort I'm sure you can get quite close but not sure how efficient it will be. You could render the HTML server-side, take a snapshot and send the image to the client but that's definitely not scalable.

The only suggestions I can think of are as follows, sorry if they are long-winded:

- How are you doing this clone? If you're going through each element and as you go through each you are creating a clone and copying the attributes one by one then this is heaavvvyy. I would strongly suggest using jQuery clone as my guess is that it's more efficient than your solution. Also, when you are making structural changes it might be useful to take advantage of jQuery's detach/remove (native JS: removeChild()) methods as this will take the element out of the DOM so you can alter it before reinserting.
- I'm not sure how you'v got your WYSIWYG, but avoid using inputs as they are heavy. If you must then I'm assuming they don't look like inputs so just swap them out with another element and style (CSS) to match. Make sure you do these swaps before you reinsert the clone in to the DOM.
- Don't literally put video at the time of showing the user comparisions. The last thing we want to do is inject 3rd party objects in to the page. Use an image, you only have to do it while comparing. Once again, do the swap before inserting the clone in to the DOM.
- I'm assuming the cloned elements won't have javascript attached to them (if there is then remove it, less moving parts is more efficiency). However, the "changed" elements will probably have some JS events attached so perhaps remove them for the period of comparision.
- Use Chrome/FF repaint/reflow tools to see how your page is working when you restructure the DOM. This is important because you could be doing some "awesome" animations that are costing you intense resources. See http://paulirish.com/2011/viewing-chromes-paint-cycle/
- Use CSS over inline styling where possible as modern browsers are optimised to handle CSS documents
- Can you make it so your users use a fast modern browser like Chrome? If it's internal then might be worth it.
- Can you do these things in Silverlight or Adobe Air? These objects get special resource privileges, so this will most likely solve your problem (according to what I'm imagining the depth of the problem is)
- This one is a bit left-field but could you open in another window? Modern browsers like Chrome will run the other window in its own process which may help.

No doubt you've probably looked in to these things more than I but good luck with it. Would be curious how you solved it.

Comment: Well, I'm _trying_ to give you the bounty, but apparently I'll have to wait a few hours... I'm curious about how air/silverlight would help, but weary because as far as I understand plugins are not so reliably usable on mobile devices. As I get more of a chance to explore the various options, I'll let you know which/what combo I find the best.

Comment: Also, is there such a thing as the too hard basket? 'cause that sounds amazing!

Answer (score 2):

You may also try: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
If it works for you canvas has way better support.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your "side-by-side" original doc and modified doc.. rather than cloning all pane1 into pane2.. could you just load the original document in an iframe next to the content you are editing?  A lot less bulky?

You could tweak how the document is displayed when it's in an iframe (e.g. hide stuff outside editable content).

And maybe when you 'save' a change, write changes to the file (or a temp) and open it up in a new iframe? That might accomplish your "multiple edit sessions"... having multiple iframes displaying the document in various states.

Just thinking out loud...

(Sorry in advance if I'm missing/misunderstanding any of your goals/requirements)

Comment: Nonono, you seem to get it fine... So, what you're saying is that loading into an iframe is less bulky than cloning nodes into the same document? I'm familiar with modifying iframe content from outside of the frame, so it could be a viable solution if it is indeed somehow more efficient... And are you talking about querying the server again for iframe content, or merely passing HTML strings or json or something to an empty iframe all on the client?

Comment: Would that I could give a little bounty to all of you! Can I just start a new bounty and award it to an existing answer?

Comment: Specifically, I meant setting the source of the iframe to the document being edited. I'm not sure if it would be more/less efficient, but i was imagining it would come down to weighing load time of the document/content in the iframe (just one dom element) vs an unknown quantity of DOM to manipulate (multiplied by 'n' side-by-side versions).  I'm not an iframe guy by any means, just brainstorming.

Comment: Nice thought but I from a conversation I've had (yes, not very official) with a chrome fanatic at a conference, the iframe runs under the same process. If that's true (I can't seem to find a reference to this to back it up) it would just decrease the efficiency as all you're doing is adding more resources.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's already the case for you but you should consider using jQuery library as it allows to perform different kinds of DOM elements manipulation such as create content and insert it into several elements at once or select an element on the page and insert it into another.

Have a look on .appendTo(), .html(), .text(), .addClass(), .css(), .attr(), .clone()

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Sorry if I'm just pointing out something you already know or even work with but your NDA is in the way of a more accurate answer.

Comment: I think JKing wants to avoid cloning. That's kind of the point of the question. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, jQuery's nice and all, but it only makes the task easier for me, not the computer that's running it - which is what I'm after. Thanks, though!